# What is the full text of the song about the failed battle of Kiska?

Tags: world-war-two, literature, alaska, ww2-pacific-theater

I came across a mention of the song about the failed [battle of Kiska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cottage) in the audiobook "The Rising Sun". I started googling, but found only two mentions, both on Google Books. Is there the full text of the song available?

> [image]

If the question is offtopic on History, feel free to move it to Literature SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The song is titled "Tales of Kiska", it's full text is located in the book [Aleutians, Gilberts & Marshalls, June 1942-April 1944](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lkzS7-TWWHwC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22that%20more%20than%20dogs%20there%20simply%20weren%27t%22&source=bl&ots=gwI2Q5uU4p&sig=ACfU3U3FQbFAfaRaGNaA-vhdlMqFHfSJ9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicwe38sOHjAhVoVBUIHSDhB64Q6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22that%20more%20than%20dogs%20there%20simply%20weren't%22&f=false).

[image: The dong "Tales of Kiska"]

```
You've heard the bloody tales of old
Of fearless knights and warriors bold,
But now the muse pens Tales of Kiska
Or, how we missed them by a whisker.

One hundred thousand men at muster,
Admirals, generals adding luster;
Two hundred planes, as many ships -
All were bound for Kiska's Nips.


And now we come to how and when
"Dog-day" got its cognomen -
"Dog-day's" evening found our log
Quoting capture of one dog.

"Dog-day" plus 1 and 2 and 3
Found three more in captivity;
But as for Japs we couldn't say
We'd seen one either night or day.

We searched bolcanic craters vast
To catch a glimpse of one at last;
It took three days before we learnt
That more than dogs there simply weren't

Refrain
O here's to mighty ComNorPac
Whose kingdom lay at cold Adak
Whose reign was known in fame for fog
And capture of two couple dog!
```

Comment: There are two minor errors in the transcription (L5: muser => muster, Refrain L3: dog => fog), which I unfortunately cannot fix as edits have to be at least 6 bytes.

Comment: Note that if this is a folk song (rather than a work that has an actual author and got famous due to mass airplay), there quite likely will be multiple alternate verses/versions floating around.